# Drag button between panels in wxPython

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, wxpython

Does anyone know of an example where it is shown how to drag a button from one panel to another in wxPython?

I have created a bitmap button in a panel, and I would like to be able to drag it to a different panel and drop I there.

I haven't found any examples using buttons, just text and files.

I am using the latest version of Python and wxPython.

Comment: it is best to put actual version numbers when referring to code/libraries etc.  It is now nine years later, and this question was not using the "latest" versions.  Although the question and accepted answer are still perfectly valid.

Comment: could you share the code from your solution?

Comment: @RufusVS, yes I agree.

Comment: @e-malito, the code was never uploaded to an online repository 14 years ago, so the code is probably gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to graphically represent the drag, one good way to do this is to create a borderless Frame that follows the mouse during a drag.  You remove the button from your source Frame, temporarily put it in this "drag Frame", and then, when the user drops, add it to your destination Frame.