# wxpython: dynamically created buttons are disabled

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I want to create buttons dynamically

```
     self.ctset = wx.BitmapButton(panel, -1, self.pic1, pos=(10,10), size=(50,50))
     self.ctset.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_ct)
     self.ctset.SetDefault()
```

and the add_ct binding function

```
def add_ct(self, event):
 
    pos=(10,self.yct)
    self.yct+=65
    self.new = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, self.pic1, pos=pos,size=(50,50))
    self.new.SetDefault()
    print "Cutset"
```

**I don't know where I am going wrong but my dynamically created buttons always seem disabled!**

I want to bind a function to the dynamically created buttons that allows me to drag them around. Any ideas would be of great help!

I am pretty new to python and wxpython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any code that captures the mouse's coordinates or even any drag-and-drop code. You need to download the wxPython demo package from the wxPython website and look at the ShapedWindow example for catching mouse coordinates. See also this old thread: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Drag-Button-around-a-Panel-td3358640.html

In it you will find someone who is doing something very similar to what you want. I also found the following links which you might find helpful:

- [Drag button between panels in wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425722/drag-button-between-panels-in-wxpython)
- [How to move items smoothly in wxPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761570/how-to-move-items-smoothly-in-wxpython)

Comment: Mike, the buttons are disabled. Even if I bind them, the functions don't get called! I am not able to interact with them directly

Comment: Try removing the SetDefault() command. Also try using regular buttons (wx.Button) to see if the behavior is the same. What OS are you on?